# Qt5 Double range slider

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

There are many postings online about trying to make a double range slider[image]

The most common answer I found is to use `libqxt`.  However, going to the [website](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/wiki/Home)  it clearly states it is not maintained due to internal api changes with newer versions of `Qt`.

Does `Qt5` provide any new functionality for this, or is there a longer lasting `Qt` implementation that provides this functionality without requiring large external libraries?

Answer (score 5):

If Qt Quick is an option, [Qt Quick Controls 2 has a `RangeSlider`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-rangeslider.html) (in three different styles). The module has tech preview status in Qt 5.6, but is a proper module in 5.7.

Here's the [Default style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-default.html) `RangeSlider`:

[image: RangeSlider GIF]

Answer (score 3):

From what I have read there are only two ways to go about getting a double range slider.

### Use Qt4

You can use Qt4 and download libqxt. Libqxt already has that feature implemented so it shouldn't be too hard if you know how to use Qt4.

### Two sliders on top of one another

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-codeeditor.html

^That doesn't explain how to use double sliders, but it may help you figure out ho to draw two sliders on top of each other.

You can also use that same technique to draw the colors in between the two values.

Comment: the link is dead :(